# Get the specified set of columns from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I manually select the columns in a pandas dataframe using

```
 df_final = df[['column1','column2'.......'column90']]
```

Instead I provide the list of column names in a list by

```
 dp_col =  [col for col in df if col.startswith('column')]
```

But not sure how to use this list to get only those set of columns from the source dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as the list of columns to select, so:

```
df_final = df[[col for col in df if col.startswith('column')]]
```

The "origin" of the list of strings is of no importance, as long as you pass a list of strings to the subscript, this will normally work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc` access with boolean masking:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('column')]
```